# Display FileName as Title on ChildForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

At the moment when a child form opens it is given a document number. Which is fine, But i want to then change the document number to show the name the file has been saved by. I attempted to make a CurrentFile function but that was only working for SDI not MDI forms and displayed only on Parent Form.

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' File, New command
    NewChildCount += 1
    Dim NewChild As New Document()
    NewChild.MdiParent = Me
    NewChild.Text = "Document " & NewChildCount.ToString
    NewChild.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' File, Open menu command.
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files *.txt | *.txt"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            sr = File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim newDoc As New Document()
            newDoc.RichTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd
            sr.Close()
            newDoc.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            newDoc.MdiParent = Me
            newDoc.Show()
            newDoc.isNamed = True
            'CurrentFileName()
            ' Move cursor to the start of the document.
            With newDoc.RichTextBox1
                .Select()
                .SelectionStart = 0
                .SelectionLength = 0
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("There was an error opening the file.")
        End Try

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SaveDocument(ByVal doc As Document, ByVal FileName As String)
    Try
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(FileName)
        sw.Write(doc.RichTextBox1.Text)
        sw.Close()
        doc.isNamed = True
        doc.isDirty = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an error saving the file.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record, you don't need to open and close a `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` like that. Just call `File.ReadAllText` or `File.WriteAllText` to open, read/write and close in a single line.

Comment: As for the issue, I used basically the same code and it worked as expected. I created a new form, set the `MdiParent` to the current form and set the `Text` to the path of the selected file and I saw multiple child forms with file paths on their title bars. Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?